# I can't use the pandas loc function but iloc works

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, geopandas

I can't use the pandas loc function but iloc works.

**My code:**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

gdf=gpd.read_file('')
df=pd.DataFrame(gdf)
df.head()
df.loc['gid']
```

**Getting error:**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'gid'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

>KeyError: 'gid'
```

Has somebody idea how can I fix this error?

Comment: Try `df.loc[:, 'gid']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this (assuming 'gid' is  a column in the dataframe)

```
df.loc[df['gid']]
```

However, this will return the entire dataframe because you are selecting the whole column  & not defining any conditions.
You can use something this like this

```
df.loc[df['gid']=='abc'] #'abc' being the content of the columns
```

Comment: I now get this error message: Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

Also, the whole dataframe shows up instead of just the gid column

Comment: as i said the whole dataframe will show up. If you want to see just one column, please do what Chris suggested `df.loc[:, 'gid']`. It will show the values of just that column & nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

loc and iloc server two different purposes. loc gets rows or columns by index *label*. iloc gets then using index *positions* which much be an integer. 
loc is structured:

```
df.loc['row', 'column']
```

If 'gid' is the name of a column, but you're passing it to loc as if it was the name of a row, then you end up with a KeyError. Instead, you  need to either specify you want all rows for that column:

```
df.loc[:, 'gid']
```

Or just specify the column directly by name:

```
df['gid']
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['fruit', 'fruit', 'vegetable'],
                   'Color': ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow'],
                   'Quantity': [4, 8, 2]
                   },
                  index=['apple', 'orange', 'bell pepper'])
print(df)
```

---

```
                  Type   Color  Quantity
apple            fruit     Red         4
orange           fruit  Orange         8
bell pepper  vegetable  Yellow         2
```

---

```
>> df.loc[:, 'Type']  

apple              fruit
orange             fruit
bell pepper    vegetable
Name: Type, dtype: object
```

---

```
>> df['Type']  

apple              fruit
orange             fruit
bell pepper    vegetable
```

---

```
>> df.loc['apple']

Type        fruit
Color         Red
Quantity        4
```

---

But there's not a row called 'Type' so:

```
>> df.loc['Type']

KeyError: 'Type'
```